# How to force ASP.NET to ignore a virtual subdirectory completely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, that resides in lets say **localhost/myapp** under IIS.

There is a virtual directory (not application) **localhost/myapp/upload** under that application in IIS (version 7+) that is mapped to a network share.

I want ASP.NET to ignore requests to files under that directory, and let IIS handle the request on its own.

I tried things like adding **routes.IgnoreRoute("upload/{*pathInfo}")** to global.asax.cs but still no luck.

Getting ASP.NET errors like **failed to start monitoring changes to '\\server\share\myupload\web.config'** when i try to access a static file e.g. a jpeg under that directory.

There is no web.config file under that upload directory. It is not an ASP.NET application. And i don't want to grant access to network service, or ASP.NET user to just let it check that no such file exists there. If i do, someone would upload an .aspx file there and execute whatever code they like in my server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this case would probably be to disable directory listing for this directory like in this tutorial :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx

And for download links, you should create a permalink database and store them in database. So if you have file at www.mysite.com/myapp/upload/file1.doc , the URL that user will see would be www.mysite.com/myapp/ControllerThatHandlesRedirect/{some guid }. All the links would be stored in database and would be taken from the database according to specific guid. So the user will not see the real URL only a GUID . The controller would select URL from database based on the permalink and redirect user to that file .

Hope that helps you